# How to use XZ / liblxma-dev to compress data using LZMA_FILTER_LZMA1 filters

Tags: c, lzma, xz

I'm trying to use liblzma to compress data using lzma1, but I'm having an issue where `lzma_stream_encoder` returns `LZMA_PROG_ERROR` before I get a chance.

I've tried modifying options and swapping in other filters, but I haven't been able to get the `lzma_stream_encoder` to return anything other than 11 for lzma1. If I swap it out with the lzma2 it does work.

### Minimal Example

```
lzma_stream stream = LZMA_STREAM_INIT;
lzma_options_lzma options;
lzma_lzma_preset(&options, LZMA_PRESET_DEFAULT);
lzma_filter filters[] = {
    {.id = LZMA_FILTER_LZMA1, .options = &options},
    {.id = LZMA_VLI_UNKNOWN, .options = NULL}
};
// this returns LZMA_PROG_ERROR (11)
lzma_stream_encoder(&stream, filters, LZMA_CHECK_CRC64);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by using source from the original lzma implementation by Igor Pavlov instead of liblzma.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).